# jQuery AJAX find element in HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to use AJAX to load a HTML page (on the same server), find an element inside that loaded HTML page and prepend it to the body. I can't use jQuery `.load()` function, because i need to prepend the element and not replace it.

For some reason something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $el = $('.element', data);
        // Returns empty object
        console.log($el);
    }
});
```

doesn't work, although the element `.element` exists in `data`. I also tried to use `.find()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694000/select-content-from-jquery-ajax-return-object) (last answer), but it doesn't work either. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be: `$el = $(data).filter('.element');` ?! In all cases, you could use: `$('<div/>',{html: data}).find('.element')`

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you so much, `.filter()` works just fine, although my `.element` is deeply nested in the html structure. I'm still wondering why `filter()` works, but `find()` doesn't?

Comment: So it is not a descendant. Check again `data`

Comment: @A.Wolff I just double checked `data` and it looks more or less like this: `<html><head>...</head><body><div class="element">Test</div></body></html>`. So it is a descendant of `html` and `body`, but for jQuery `body` is probably the "root". Anyway it finally works!

Comment: jQuery strips out HTML and BODY tags when wrapping it. EDIT: could be related to javascript indeed

Answer (score 0):

My loaded HTML page looked more or less like:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div class="element">Test</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks to @A.Wolff, who pointed out that jQuery strips out both the HTML and the BODY tag when wrapping it. Thus `.element` is not a descendant and `.find()` or `$('.element', data)` didn't work.

In any case you can simply use:

```
$('<div/>',{ 
    html: data 
}).find('.element');
```

... or in this case simply:

```
$(data).filter('.element');
```