# Retriving data from external site

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Does anyone have a solution to how to retrieve data from http://www.rafisklaget.no/portal/page/portal/NR/PrisogStatistikk/Statistikkbank/Landingsopplysninger

This is data that is publicly available and can be used freely. You must click on the "Vis aktive fartøy siste uke / Show active vessels last week" button to get an overview of active boats for the last week. Then click on the link that is in the "Reg. merke / Reg.mark" column. Then you get the data I'm interested in downloading. This is something I would like to do on every active vessel, every day.

Want to get downloaded data to MySQL, and the hope was that this could be automated so I could run this using a Cron job on server. That is, least possible processing of data.

I have previously been in contact with Råfisklaget to hear if it was possible to send / retrieve the data in CSV format, but I did not get any answer.

Comment: If you click that little printer icon on the right side it'll take you to http://www.rafisklaget.no/portal/page/portal/NR/PrisogStatistikk/Statistikkbank/Landingsopplysninger which should be easier to scrape than the regular page. Use [DomDocument](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to scrape the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use inspector then "Network" get the url of the resource you want and use that url to get your data.
There is also engines to that too.
here :

> http://www.rafisklaget.no/portal/pls/portal/PORTAL.LANDINGSOPPLYSNING_AKTIVE.show

it's a html page.
it's like any other html you can get it with jQuery get/load or ajax methods, give the the result to the query and select the table and rows and columns that please you.

```
$.get("http://stackoverflow.com", function(html) {
    var $res = $(html);
    var $table = $('table', $res);
    var $rows = $('table tr',$res); // or
    var $cols = $('td', $table); // this would be a little faster
});
```

this is helpful too : 
[Select content from JQuery ajax return object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694000/select-content-from-jquery-ajax-return-object)

but this very particular site of yours require an active session that need more job to be done, I suggest you read the page's source code and look at "***function* hentAktive()**" .

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful  :-)

Comment: Has created a script that downloads data as HTML, but wants to get it in CSV format. Also have a desire to do this in an operation for about 6000 inputs at one time without having to create a script containing hundreds of thousands of lines. :-)

Comment: <? Php
  $ ch = curl_init ();
  curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.rafisklag.no/portal/pls/portal/PORTAL.LANDINGSLIST.show?p_arg_names=p_regmerke&p_arg_values=T%200182T');
  curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt ($ ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
  $ data = curl_exec ($ ch);
  file_put_contents ("rpt / $ date T 0182T.html", $ data);
  curl_close ($ ch);
?>

Comment: Just really want to get the first values ​​in the table, ie the data that is within the red frame of the image. Also want data marked with red arrows copied down to the next date. This would save me too much manual work :-)

http://www.ferskfesk.no/infoflyt/upload/img.png

Is this possible to do this? This is a bit new to me, so I ask a lot, but try to teach me this :-) The more I can automate, the better :-) The idea is to download this data, convert it to a format that can be loaded in a MySQL database once a day.

Comment: @RuneLarsen . . .